# Is Everything Compatible?

Tags: compatibility, computer-building

I've recently decided to build a Custom Gaming PC and one of my friends has decided to help help me find and pick the parts. Everything looks great but my only concern is that we're not 101% sure that this will be guaranteed to work so I was wondering if it will. Here is a link to the specs:

https://pcpartpicker.com/list/M3ffkT

Thanks you for your time 
-Cross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That build should work with no issues.However in my experience Cooler Master Hyper 212 Evo is a bit hard to install.Other than that it's a pretty neat build.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and to see that it will work great, do you have any recommendations for a cpu fan that would work with my future build?

Comment: @CrosssCloudGP Hardware product recommendations are off topic here. Please don't pester users to give you them.

Comment: alright I'm sorry, I am new to this website